# Python Recursion: Are there any advantages to passing all variables vs just declaring a global variable and re-declaring in the function?

Tags: python

When I look at python code I see two styles of handling variables in python.

1. pass all variables.

Example

```
#initialize
variable1 = 1
variable2 = 1
variable3 = 1

def recursive(variable1, variable2, variable3):
    do stuff with variables
    recursive(variable1, variable2, variable3)
```

2. if a variable doesn't need a separate instance inside the function, just make it global

example

```
#initialize
variable1 = 1
global variable2 
variable2 = 1
global variable3 
variable3 = 1

def recursive(variable1):
    global variable2
    global variable3
    do stuff variables
    recursive(variable1)
```

Are there any advantages to either style? Is one more 'pythonic' than the other?

Comment: This is too big to answer, really. Just google _"why are global variables bad"_. Or simply assume that they are. Here is one google result: http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad

Comment: You really need a more concrete and specific question, or the only real answer is “it depends”. For example, does this recursive function need to be reentrant? Or even threadsafe? Could it be moved into a class that has these values as attributes? Or even _turned_ into a class? Or maybe a helper function with variables that can be captured in a closure? Each of those things is appropriate in some cases, and not in others.

Comment: Using global state, especially *mutable* global state (as in, you re-assign variables, not that they necessarily refer to mutable objects) is generally considered an anti-pattern. It makes your programs harder to reason about and harder to debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `global` excessively can be tricky to debug. The pythonic way is definitely to pass everything explicitly or encapsulate the work into smaller functions so that there isn't so much verbosity messing with all three variables.

In your case, there might be an easier approach:

```
def recursive(*args)
    # Do stuff with args
    recursive(*args)
```

This eliminates a lot of the verbosity you might not have cared for.